# Find text in string and replace in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

I have a string:

```
$string = 'I love my kitty and other animals.'; 

$categories = array(
    'kitty' => 'cat',
    'teddy' => 'bear',
    'someting' => 'other',
);
```

I would like to make a function which find a text in array and convert them.
Someting like:

```
function find_animal_in_string($string)
{
    // If $string contains one of the element in array print this array value
    // how to do that?
}
```

So my preferred result will be:

```
echo $this->find_animal_in_string('I love my leon and other animals.') //echo cat
echo $this->find_animal_in_string('I do not like teddys in mountains.') //echo bear
```

Will appreciate your help. I have tried strpos and array_key_exists but did not work for me.

Comment: what is the question here ?

Comment: how to make a function which prints that results?

Comment: make a function, print the result ? have you tried anything ?

Comment: you have to replace leon with cat ryt?

Comment: I have tired array_key_exists and strtr but can't find a proper results

Comment: `leon` won't work because it's not in your `$categories` array. Your second example has `teddys` but in your array you have `teddy`. Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service where we will develop complex language algorithms. We are here to help with specific issues you may have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `strpos` to check the string exists or not

```
foreach($categories as $key => $value){


 if(strpos($string,$key) == true)

    echo $value;


}
```

Comment: Fails because you can't find `leon` in the array and this fails on the comparison between `teddys` and `teddy`. Although, this solution would work if OP had a nice array

Comment: works after I have cahnged "== true" to "!== false". Thx for contribution

Answer (score 1):

```
function find_animal_in_string($string)
{
// If $string contains one of the element in array print this array 
// how to do that?
 $categories = array(
'kitty' => 'cat',
'teddy' => 'bear',
'someting' => 'other',
 );
foreach($categories as $cle => $value){
    if(strpos($string,$cle) != FALSE){
    echo $value;
    }
 }
}   

    find_animal_in_string('I do not like teddy in mountains.');//echo bear
```

Comment: You could pass `global $categories` to get the array out of the function scope. However, this fails because the example provided by OP is `teddys` not `teddy` and this doesn't pass OP's first example of `leon`

Comment: he must add leon and teddys in the array $categories. is only an example

Comment: thank you, I have changed only "!= FALSE" for "!== FALSE" to make sure it will also work for first element

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that with regex:

```
function find_animal_in_string($string)
{
// global $categories
        $matches = "/(".join("|", array_keys($categories)).")/";
        preg_match($matches, $string, $hit);
        return $categories[$hit[0]];
}
```

And don't forget about the visibility of $categories